# How to make a copy of argv[1]

Tags: c, arrays, command-line, command-line-arguments, argv

How would I copy argv[1] into a usable char * 
I and ciphering using a word as the key so I need to be able to have a copy of argv[1] to use a char *.

Comment: How about `strcpy()` ?

Comment: Why do you need to make a copy ? Unless your enciphering algorithm modifies the key (odd that), it would seem the one you have would be sufficient. Regardless, some buffer space, `strcpy` and you're on your way.

Comment: `strdup()` is very useful if you just want to make a copy.

Answer (score 3):

You may be missing the point that `argv[1]` is *already* a `char *`, since `argv` is an array of `char*`, but maybe you need to modify `argv[1]` for some inscrutable reason:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  //Method 1
  char *myCopy = strdup(argv[1]);
  printf("%s\n", myCopy);
  free(myCopy); myCopy = NULL;

  //Method 2
  char myCopy2[50];
  strcpy(myCopy2, argv[1]);
  printf("%s\n", myCopy2);

  return 0;
}
```

Note that `argc` should be checked to avoid a crash if the user doesn't supply `argv[1]` (and of course if you use method2, you should ensure your buffer is long enough to take the user's input)